# Can't understand how VLAN Tagging, Untagging Works

Tags: networking, vlan

I'm trying to setup a 48 ports gigabit switch (netgear GS748T).

My goal is to split the 48 ports to 3 vlans :

- VLAN10 ports 2-20
- VLAN20 ports 21-30
- VLAN30 ports 31-46

What i did is :

- On VLAN1, TAG port 1, UNTAG every other ports
- On VLAN10, TAG PORTS 2-20, UNTAG every other ports
- On VLAN20, TAG PORTS 21-30, UNTAG every other ports
- On VLAN30, TAG PORTS 31-46, UNTAG every other ports

I didn't touch the PVID configuration page; don't know what this is.

Now, if i plug a cable to port 5, i can ping VLAN20 and VLAN30; same for VLAN20 i can ping VLAN10 and VLAN30.

What am I doing wrong here ? I'm quite new to VLANs ...

edit: 
VLAN10 is WAN (connected to firewall interface x0, public subnet/26)
VLAN20 is MGMT (connected to firewall interface x4, 10.0.0.x/24)

Whenever i plug from firewall to vlan20 i see all ports of the switch go crazy and i have packet loss when pinging switch or accessing his web ui.

Comment: You definitely don't want more than one VLAN untagged on a single port!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do you want to have any trunk-port [port that combines more than one vlan] or do you just want to have total traffic separation for three groups?

if the second - i suggest you:

- leave port 1 as it is for experimentation
- set up vlan10 - port 2-20 untagged, all other ports blank [not member]
- set up vlan20 - ports 21-30 untagged, all other ports blank [not member]
- set up vlan30 - ports 31-46 untagged, all other ports blank [not member]

Comment: Ideally, yes i'd like to have ports than can be member of multiple vlans.

Comment: also, switch has an IP address that is part of the vlan10 (wan)

Comment: i want to be able to access the switch admin ip from port 1 (when i'm in datacenter) and from wan (vlan10)

Comment: edited question: added firewall

Comment: i'm not sure if it'll be possible to manage the switch from two different vlans [port 1 in vlan 1 and some port on vlan10]. making switch reachable from the internet is not a very good idea [from the security perspective].

Comment: right, i'll put in 10.x.x.x range and i should tag it vlan10 as well ?

Comment: then you have to tell the switch to use vlan10 for management.

Comment: Should i tag the port that is connected to the firewall ?

Comment: it depends if your firewall is expecting tagged or untagged frames.

Comment: Sonicwall NSA2400 how do i figure out ?

Comment: it depends on the design you want to have. if you dont know - most probably port without tagging will be ok.

Comment: Most all NetGear switches in this class do not have HTTPS / SSL.  So remote access to the switch will require a SSH tunnel or some other form of VPN. Alternatively would be to remote access a desktop on the management vLan and then have that access the switch.

Comment: Setting port 15 in the PVID page with the value 10 will tag all ingress into the switch on port 15 with vLan.10.